# Why does the margin apply only when .info is active

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Why does the 50px margin between the two lists only appear when .info is active? The gap should always be there and the text should appear within the gap once number 1-8 is selected. All suggestions are welcome.

```js
// Get references to the two sets of boxes
var numbers = document.querySelectorAll(".click");
var letters = document.querySelectorAll(".border");

// Turn each node list into proper arrays:
numbers = Array.prototype.slice.call(numbers);
letters = Array.prototype.slice.call(letters);

// Loop through all the number boxes
numbers.forEach(function(box, index){

  // Set up the click event handlers for all the number boxes
  box.addEventListener("click", function(){
  
    // Remove borders from each of the letter boxes
    letters.forEach(function(box){
      box.classList.remove("showBorder");
    });
      
    // Apply the border to only the one clicked element
    var info = document.getElementsByClassName('info')[0];
   
    info.style.display = 'inline';
    letters[index].classList.add("showBorder");
  });
  
});
```

```css
.list-box li {display: inline-block;list-style-type: none;padding: 1em;background:red;}
.list-box {margin:50px auto;padding:0;}
.box-sleeve li {display: inline-block;list-style-type: none;padding: 1em;background:red;}
.box-sleeve {margin:50px auto;padding:0;}
.showBorder { border: 3px dashed black; }
.info {margin:auto; position: relative;padding-left:3em;display:none}
```

```html
                   <ul class="list-box">
                       <li class="click">1</li>
                       <li class="click">2</li>
                       <li class="click">3</li>
                       <li class="click">4</li>
                       <li class="click">5</li>
                       <li class="click">6</li>
                       <li class="click">7</li>
                       <li class="click">8</li>
                   </ul> 
                <div class="info">Regular length for your collar size</div>
                   <ul class="box-sleeve">
                       <li class="border">a</li>
                       <li class="border">b</li>
                       <li class="border">c</li>
                       <li class="border">d</li>
                       <li class="border">e</li>
                       <li class="border">f</li>
                       <li class="border">g</li>
                       <li class="border">h</li>
                   </ul>
```

Comment: The problem is your LI (.click) style, which is inline. Make it inline-block & it will fix.

Comment: @Zri I have edited my question with your suggestion however still got the same issue.

Comment: You can additionaly have:
.list-box {
    padding: 50px 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
// Get references to the two sets of boxes
var numbers = document.querySelectorAll(".click");
var letters = document.querySelectorAll(".border");

// Turn each node list into proper arrays:
numbers = Array.prototype.slice.call(numbers);
letters = Array.prototype.slice.call(letters);

// Loop through all the number boxes
numbers.forEach(function(box, index){

  // Set up the click event handlers for all the number boxes
  box.addEventListener("click", function(){
  
    // Remove borders from each of the letter boxes
    letters.forEach(function(box){
      box.classList.remove("showBorder");
    });
      
    // Apply the border to only the one clicked element
    var info = document.getElementsByClassName('info')[0];
   
    info.style.visibility = 'visible';
    letters[index].classList.add("showBorder");
  });
  
});
```

```css
.list-box li {display: inline-block;list-style-type: none;padding: 1em;background:red;}
.list-box {margin:50px auto;padding:0;}
.box-sleeve li {display: inline-block;list-style-type: none;padding: 1em;background:red;}
.box-sleeve {margin:50px auto;padding:0;}
.showBorder { border: 3px dashed black; }
.info {margin:auto; position: relative;padding-left:3em; visibility: hidden;}
```

```html
 <ul class="list-box">
                       <li class="click">1</li>
                       <li class="click">2</li>
                       <li class="click">3</li>
                       <li class="click">4</li>
                       <li class="click">5</li>
                       <li class="click">6</li>
                       <li class="click">7</li>
                       <li class="click">8</li>
                   </ul> 
                <div class="info">Regular length for your collar size</div>
                   <ul class="box-sleeve">
                       <li class="border">a</li>
                       <li class="border">b</li>
                       <li class="border">c</li>
                       <li class="border">d</li>
                       <li class="border">e</li>
                       <li class="border">f</li>
                       <li class="border">g</li>
                       <li class="border">h</li>
                   </ul>
```

Instead of `display:none`

Get rid of `display`

and include

`visibility:hidden`

When the click is invoked set `visibility:visible` to the info element.

Comment: who would have thought. works like a charm. best regards